# DJANGO: request.COOKIES['sessionid'] does not exist on Firefox browser

Tags: python, django, firefox

I'm writing a module to store comments for specific article. My model contains a column `unique_session` which is intended to store the *commenter's browsing session id*.

[image]

Within my view function, I'm trying to initialize a variable bearing the value of `request.COOKIES['sessionid']` which I later assign to `unique_session` column of the model.

[image]

So far, I'm doing good with Chrome. I'm able to get it as the key exists when I inspect it, and obviously it stores to db just fine.

[image]

But when I go to Firefox, the `sessionid` cookie does not exist and Django throws in a KeyError.

[image]

[image]

Anyone have any idea what could be missing?

**P.S.** I was not manually creating the `sessionid` cookie. I saw it exists in Chrome so I just used it instead of creating my own 32-bit session key. Then I later realized that it does not exist on Firefox. So I have no idea when/where it gets created and why not on Firefox.

Comment: Login any account in firefox, try and report

Comment: Don't do any of this. Use the actual Django session functionality.

Comment: @DanielRoseman isn't request.COOKIES['sessionid'] a native Django session functionality? I never created this cookie but it exists on Chrome. Also I've read that Django set the default value of DJANGO_COOKIE_NAME's as 'sessionid'

Comment: `request.session.session_key` is what @DanielRoseman intends. By explicitly using the cookie you're making assumptions on how the session id is passed around.

Comment: @dirkgroten oh yeah yeah that. I have used this before using ['sessionid']...  it did not give me the runtime error, but it returns empty on Firefox though... I am not sure why the issue on FF browser (or is it really an issue or I'm missing something i.e. some additional configuration on settings.py)

Comment: is the user logged in? Note django only creates a session (and sends the session id to the browser) when it's really necessary, i.e. either when the user logs in or when you actually set some key/value in the session. Open a new private window in Chrome, fetch your site and you'll see: no session id cookie.